# Mount USB drive in linux with C

Tags: c, linux, usb

I am looking to programatically mount a USB drive in Linux, so that I can write a text document using fprintf. I am having trouble finding out how to mount the drive. I have been searching the web for an answer, and I found many tutorials of how to do it via the command line, but none in C. Can someone please point me in the right direction with this.

Comment: Have a look at the mount manpage - http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mount.2.html Short version call the mount syscall

Comment: @mru: I believe that it can be posted as answer. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
man 2 mount
```

e.g.

```
#include <sys/mount.h>

if (mount("/dev/mmcblk0p1", "/mnt/sd", "vfat", MS_NOATIME, NULL)) {
    if (errno == EBUSY) {
        printf("Mountpoint busy");
    } else {
        printf("Mount error: %s", strerror(errno));
    }
} else {
    printf("Mount successful");
}
```

Comment: This is in no way critique! How do i interpret what's written in the manpages and come up with a properly formed (like the one above) mount call in C?

Comment: How do transform this information into a mount call?

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.20 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0951 ProdID=1666 Rev=01.10
S:  Manufacturer=Kingston
S:  Product=DataTraveler 3.0
S:  SerialNumber=4CED0000A3AAAAA039970000
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=504mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=1024 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=1024 Ivl=0ms